# How do I force the page height view in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Someone sent me a document and it seems to have changed the default on my PC, now whenever I open a Word document the pages (I am in Print layout) are only as high as the content. How do I reset the view to make all of the pages the correct size regardless of amount of content on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2003 go to Tools --> Options.

On the "View" tab go down to "Print and Web Layout Options".

There is a checkbox for "White space between pages (Print View Only)"
Make sure it is checked.

If you have 2007, go to the Office Button and down to Word Options.
On the "Display" button, it is the first checkbox.

Comment: You are a savior, that was really starting to drive me crazy.. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I only know about it because it drove me crazy when I saw it.